# Notepad++ regex ad lines, copy strings and alter them

Tags: regex, notepad++

i want to search replace & strings in thousands of wavefront *.mtl files to ad many new Texture links. Is this even possible with Notepad++ regex? I´ve already altered this files very often with regex but this task is way over my head!

At the current state i got many Materialparts in every file looking like this.

```
newmtl Material__28  
    Ns 0.000000  
    Ni 1.500000  
    d 1.000000  
    Tr 0.000000  
    Tf 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   
    illum 2  
    Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  
    Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000  
    Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000  

    map_Kd textures\wall_exterior_wood_02.png
```

And afterwards it should contain the NRM & Spec pngs named exactly like the first map_Kd.

Example:

```
newmtl Material__28  
    Ns 0.000000  
    Ni 1.500000  
    d 1.000000  
    Tr 0.000000  
    Tf 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   
    illum 2  
    Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  
    Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000  
    Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000  

    map_Kd textures\wall_exterior_wood_02.png
    map_bump textures\wall_exterior_wood_02_nrm.png
    map_bump textures\wall_exterior_wood_02_nrm alternative.png
    map_Ks textures\wall_exterior_wood_02_spec.png
```

Important is that the naming of the pngs should be the same except for the prefixes "`map_bump`", "`map_Ks`" and the postfixes "`_nrm`","`_nrm alternative`","`_spec`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `map_Kd (.*)\.png` with 
`map_Kd \1.png\r\nmap_bump \1_nrm.png\r\nmap_bump \1_nrm alternative.png\r\nmap_Ks \1_spec.png`. That should do the trick.

Comment: darthmaim you are my hero!